# Zero return in measuring time of function

Tags: python

```
import time  
def find(a):  
    count = 0  
    for item in a:  
        count = count + 1  
        if item == 2:  
            return count  

a = [7,4,5,10,3,5,88,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,55,
     5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,55,5,5,5,5,5,
     5,5,5,5,5,2,5,5,5,55,5,55,5,5,5,6]
print (len(a))  

sTime = time.time()  
print (find(a))  
eTime = time.time()  

ave = eTime - sTime  
print (ave)
```

I want measure the execution time of this function
My **print (ave)** returns 0; why?

Comment: It does not print 0, it prints something like `0.001...`

Comment: code is working correctly, `8.058547973632812e-05` was the value I received.

Comment: It takes so little time that Python is displaying it as zero. Try a slower computer.

Comment: Suggest you use `timeit` in the standard library instead:  https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/timeit.html

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time). Note:   "Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second". If you are on Windows, you can try `time.clock` or better yet, use `timeit`

Answer (score 1):

To accurately time code execution you should use the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), rather than `time`. `timeit` easily allows the repetition of code blocks for timing to avoid very near zero results (the cause of your question)

```
import timeit

s = """
def find(a):  
    count = 0  
    for item in a:  
        count = count + 1  
        if item == 2:  
            return count  

a = [7,4,5,10,3,5,88,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,55,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,55,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,2,5,5,5,55,5,55,5,5,5,6]  
find(a)
"""
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=s, number=100000))
```

This will measure the amount of time it takes to run the code in multiline string `s` 100,000 times. Note that I replaced `print(find(a))` with just `find(a)` to avoid having the result printed 100,000 times.

Running many times is advantageous for several reasons:

- In general, code runs very quickly.  Summing many quick runs results in a number which is actually meaningful and useful
- Run time is dependent on many variable, uncontrollable factors (such as other processes using computing power).  Running many times helps normalize this
- If you are using `timeit` to compare two methodologies to see which is faster, multiple runs will make it easier to see the conclusive result

Comment: *"`time` ... lacks the accuracy required."* This is inaccurate. I'd be extremely surprised if `timeit` didn't use `time.time()` for grabbing timestamps.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, took a look through it and you're right.  My confusion came from remembering discussion of inaccuracy regarding `time.sleep`, but that only applies to that one function.  Thanks for the correction

Comment: why do you comment it and assign it to `s` and run `100,000 times`?

Comment: @Samin, the "comment" is a mutli-line string; if you did `print(type(s))` you would get `<type 'str'>`.  Question on running 100,000 is answered in edit

Comment: @samin, if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted" so that future readers can easily find the solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, either; I get a time about 1.4E-5.
Try putting the call into a loop to measure more iterations:

```
for i in range(10000):
    result = find(a)
print(result)
```